# Multiple internet connections being used.

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Say, on my computer I happen to have three internet sources.

1. USB tether from my phone
2. WiFi to my home network
3. Ethernet to another router different from my wifi.

I want to use 1 to brows the web. 2 to transfer files to another machine in the house and 3 to transfers other files to other machines.

The above is an overly exaggerated use case. Most likely option 3 wont exist.

Is this possible?

How?

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(you don't say what OS so I am assuming windows for this, other OS's have similar commands)

This can easily be set up via the [route](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/route.mspx?mfr=true) command in windows.

```
route [-f] [-p] [Command [Destination] [mask Netmask] [Gateway] [metric Metric]] [if Interface]]
```

You would need to set up 3 routes

1. Default connection that uses the USB Teather
2. A route for a single computer to use the WiFi
3. A route for the rest of the local connections

Assumes:

- `192.168.0.1` is the IP of the gateway on the tether
- The interface ID of the WiFi is `11`
- `192.168.1.3` is the IP of the "other computer".
- The interface ID of the Ethernet is `12`
- The subnet of the Ethernet is `192.168.2.0` with a netmask of `255.255.255.0`

Adding the default gateway (also `-f` clears out any old routes already set up)

```
route -f -p ADD  0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1
```

Add the route for the "other comptuer" that is connected via WiFi (as long as the subnet is different than network 3 you could just use the same command as the 3rd command for the `192.168.1.0` subnet if you wanted every computer on your home network to work instead of just one or adding them individually)

```
route -p ADD 192.168.1.3 if 11
```

Add the route so the rest of the computers in the 192.168.2.x range are all via the wired Ethernet

```
route -p ADD 192.168.2.0 mask 255.255.255.0 if 12
```