# Two NICs work together

Tags: windows-8, routing

I got two NICs in my windows, one is Ethernet and the other one is wireless.

Now I want the Two NICs to work together

1. Use wireless to access the Internet. -> (192.168.1.0/24)
2. Use Ethernet to access local network.-> (172.16.1.1/24)
so I added something to the route table like this

```
Ipv4 Route Table
================================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination     Netmask          Gateway        Interface      Metric
      0.0.0.0           0.0.0.0          192.168.1.1    192.168.1.101  2
      127.0.0.0         255.0.0.0         On-link       127.0.0.1      306
      127.0.0.1         255.255.255.255   On-link       127.0.0.1      306
   127.255.255.255      255.255.255.255   On-link       127.0.0.1      306
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
Network Address         Netmask    Gateway Address  Metric
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        192.168.1.1     1
     172.16.1.0      255.255.255.0    172.16.1.1      10
===========================================================================
```

the result is that I can access to the Internet, but it's VERY VERY slow.

any ideas?

Comment: On your local network do you ever access computers outside of the 172.16.1.x range and if so what is the range of the local network? [Windows does not support multiple gateways if the gateways are on disjointed networks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/159168), please provide more information on your network setup and I can tell you the correct way to set up your route table.

Comment: I cannot access computers outside of the 172.16.1.x range through local network. what information should I provide?

Comment: if you don't use computers outside of the 172.16.1.x range then what is 172.16.1.1 and why are you using it as a gateway?

Comment: my local ip is 172.16.1.10, if I do not add 172.16.1.1 as a gateway, Can I access to computers who has ip 172.16.1.x?

Comment: yes, the point of the gateway is to access someone who has 172.16.**2**.x, if you don't need to access anything outside of the 172.16.1.1/24 range just leave the gateway blank and it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to access computes in the `172.16.1.1/24` subnet on the ethernet network card just don't set any gateway on the NIC for that interface, [windows does not support multiple gateways on disjointed networks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/159168).

The reason you are seeing slowness is Windows [Dead Gateway Detection Algorithm](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/128978/EN-US) is trying to get to the internet on your eithernet card without trying the wireless card. By only having one gateway it will immediately try the wireless card.

[Here is a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/641444/multiple-internet-connections-being-used) to what you are asking where I go in to a little more depth and show how do do the setup via command line commands.

Comment: well, I tried to add a route `route -p add 172.16.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 if 13`(my wired Ethernet card id is 13) but failed. error message is `Invalid MASK generates an error, that is when (DEST & MASK)!= DEST.` I cannot understand why.

Comment: it seems that behind `mask 255.255.255.0` should come with gateway ip. if I use `route -p add 172.16.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 172.16.1.1 if 13` then no problem reported.

Answer (score 0):

The pc will automatically forward any traffic going to 172.16.1.x to the ethernet interface (assuming it's correctly configured with an ip from this subnet, e.g. 172.16.1.10), there's no need for the route you are trying to add.

The pc will use the default route 0.0.0.0/0 only for traffic that is not going to 172.16.1.x.

Can you try to run the pc with the default routing tables without any changes, and see if this works ? Can you also provide the routing table with the default behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually what I should do is very easy.
After connecting to the wired and wireless network, windows will setup route table automatically like the following.

```
Ipv4 Route Table
================================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination     Netmask          Gateway        Interface      Metric
  0.0.0.0               0.0.0.0          192.168.1.1    192.168.1.101  2
  0.0.0.0               0.0.0.0          172.16.1.1     172.16.1.1     2
  127.0.0.0             255.0.0.0         On-link       127.0.0.1      306
  127.0.0.1             255.255.255.255   On-link       127.0.0.1      306
127.255.255.255         255.255.255.255   On-link       127.0.0.1      306
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
Network Address         Netmask    Gateway Address  Metric
===========================================================================
```

there are two `0.0.0.0` in the Network Destination table. what I need to do is to delete the `0.0.0.0` with Interface `172.16.1.1`,  Use command `route delete 0.0.0.0`, but this will delete both of the Interface `192.168.1.1` and `172.16.1.1`, so I need to add the interface `192.168.1.1` back, Use command `route -p add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1 if 13 metric 1`(My wireless NIC id is 13) . Then this solved my problem. Thanks to @aseaudi and  @Scott Chamberlain.