# Setting multiple gateway for internet connection

Tags: windows, networking, internet, gateway

In our office we have windows xp and 8 pc connected in network.We are using about 4 internet connections. But in pc only one default gateway is set.But if one internet connection is failed then internet will not be available and user has to change default gateway to another and try.

So instead of is there any method of adding all gateway and if one does not work(internet connection not available) other will take over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows most centrally supports "[Dead Gateway Detection](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/128978/EN-US)", however all of the gateways **CAN NOT** be connected to [disjointed networks.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/159168) That means if I send send a packet to `198.252.206.16` (the ip of superuser.com) to any gateway on the list the packet must be able to get through. If any of the gateways are their own special private network's you can not use them as one of the "Default Gateways" (But you can statically add a route with the [route command](https://superuser.com/questions/641444/multiple-internet-connections-being-used/641476#641476)).

Simply open the TCP/IP settings and click on the `Advanced` button

[image]

From there you can add as many gateways as you want.

[image]

If you have "better" gateways than others you can manually set the metric for each gateway, windows will attempt to use lower metric gateways first, [here is a list of the values](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299540) windows puts in if you leave the metric on "automatic metric"

Comment: Your solution works fine.But if one gateway does not work then it selects another gateway with higher metric.But if higher metric gateway does not work after sometime (and lower metrics starts working) then it does come back to lower metric gateway. Also if a gateway fails then it takes about 2 minutes to switch to another.

Comment: That is correct, if you want better gateway handling then what XP can provide you will need to put a single router (perhaps a Linux box or other managed router) that acts a gateway for the whole network, then use whatever configuration that router supports for multiple gateways and it will choose the correct gateway to get on to the internet for the rest of the computers behind it.

Comment: Can we configure only default gateway IP using "Routeadd" command? Here IP address for PC is fixed, and subnet mask too. Only the default gateway should change based on the command we pass. Is der any option like this?

Comment: You could make some sort of [daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) process that would hop gateways faster than the default behavior.